# How can i count the number of moves taken to complete my python slider puzzle?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a sliding puzzle game in Python, where there is a n x n grid with each square having a number except one, which is blank, the player inputs a number that is beside or above/below the blank square to swap places with it. After each valid move, the grid is updated and printed before asking the player for their next move, unless the puzzle is solved. The game's aim is to have all the numbers in numerical order, with the last square blank. I need help counting the number of moves a player took to complete the puzzle.

I have tried using number_of_moves initialised to zero and adding one, every time the player makes a move. However, when the number of moves is printed, it always prints "number of moves = 0", and then "number of moves = 1". this happens no matter how many moves I take to solve the puzzle. The code i have written so far is:

```
def milestone_2(tiles):
    def valid_moves(tiles_list, grid_size):
        number_moves = 0
        while tiles_list[:-1] != sorted(tiles_list[:-1]) and tiles_list[-1] != "":    
            while True:
                choice = input("Your move: ")
                if choice == 'quit':
                    print("Quitting...")
                    return
                if choice not in tiles_list:
                    print(f"{choice} is not valid. Try again.")
                    number_moves += 1
                    continue
                blank_square_index = tiles_list.index("")
                choice_index = tiles_list.index(choice)
                if abs(choice_index - blank_square_index) == grid_size or ((choice_index // grid_size) == (blank_square_index // grid_size)) and (abs(choice_index - blank_square_index)) == 1 :
                    tiles_list[blank_square_index], tiles_list[choice_index] = tiles_list[choice_index], tiles_list[blank_square_index]
                    milestone_2(','.join(tiles_list))
                    number_moves += 1
                    break   
                else:
                    print(f"{choice} is not valid. Try again.")
                    number_moves += 1
        print(f"You won in {number_moves} moves. Congratulations!")
        
    def create_grid():          
        tiles_list = tiles.split(',')
        grid_size = int(len(tiles_list) ** 0.5)
        result = "┌" + ("────┬") * (grid_size -1) + "────┐\n" 
        for i in range(0, len(tiles_list), grid_size):
            result += "│"
            for j in range(grid_size):
                tile = tiles_list[i+j]
                if tile == "":
                    result += "    │"
                elif len(tile) == 1:
                    result += "  " + tile + " │"    
                elif len(tile) == 2:
                    result += " " + tile + " │"
            result += "\n"
            if i < len(tiles_list) - grid_size:
                result += "├" + (grid_size-1) * "────┼" + "────┤\n"
        result += "└" + (grid_size-1)*"────┴" + "────┘"
        print(result)
        valid_moves(tiles_list, grid_size)
    create_grid()

milestone_2("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,,15")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 2 outputs

> You won in 0 moves. Congratulations!
> You won in 1 moves. Congratulations!

because you have called milestone_2() function within the same function.

```
if abs(choice_index - blank_square_index) == grid_size or ((choice_index // grid_size) == (blank_square_index // grid_size)) and (abs(choice_index - blank_square_index)) == 1 :
                tiles_list[blank_square_index], tiles_list[choice_index] = tiles_list[choice_index], tiles_list[blank_square_index]
                milestone_2(','.join(tiles_list))
                number_moves += 1
                break
```

Correct it to,

```
if abs(choice_index - blank_square_index) == grid_size or ((choice_index // grid_size) == (blank_square_index // grid_size)) and (abs(choice_index - blank_square_index)) == 1 :
                tiles_list[blank_square_index], tiles_list[choice_index] = tiles_list[choice_index], tiles_list[blank_square_index]
                number_moves += 1
                break
```

and give it a try

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking to answer my question, the problem is that that line of code is the line that updates the grid, and prints it, so the user can see what move they made, and what other valid moves they can make next. That does work in telling the user how many moves they took, but it isn't the answer I'm looking for,